# capture video with kinect using libfreenect

Tags: ffmpeg, kinect, openkinect

i m trying to use kinect to capture video for video/image processing purposes
i found there is an script in libfreenect/build/bin folder named fakenect-record can do this for me

when i use it,it  start capturing rgb and depth data in ppm and pgm format(both are images) and also it has an option (-ffmpeg) witch make an avi file of video but the problem is when I that it it fails and says this error :

```
Depth Mode: {256, 1, {0}, 614400, 640, 480, 11, 5, 30, 1}
Video Mode: {256, 1, {0}, 921600, 640, 480, 24, 0, 30, 1}
[Stream 70] Expected 1748 data bytes, but got 948
ffmpeg -pix_fmt rgb24 -s 640x480 -f rawvideo -i /dev/stdin -aspect 4:3 -r 20 -vcodec msmpeg4 -b 30000k sadra-depth.avi
ffmpeg -pix_fmt rgb24 -s 640x480 -f rawvideo -i /dev/stdin -aspect 4:3 -r 20 -vcodec msmpeg4 -b 30000k sadra-rgb.avi
ffmpeg version N-76045-g97be5d4ffmpeg version N-76045-g97be5d4 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers

  built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)
  configuration: --extra-libs=-ldl --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --enable-avresample --disable-debug --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --disable-decoder=amrnb --disable-decoder=amrwb --enable-libpulse --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libvorbis --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvpx --enable-libspeex --enable-libass --enable-avisynth --enable-libsoxr --enable-libxvid --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvidstab
  built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)
  configuration: --extra-libs=-ldl --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --enable-avresample --disable-debug --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --disable-decoder=amrnb --disable-decoder=amrwb --enable-libpulse --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libvorbis --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvpx --enable-libspeex --enable-libass --enable-avisynth --enable-libsoxr --enable-libxvid --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvidstab
  libavutil      55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100
  libavutil      55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100
  libavcodec     57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
  libavcodec     57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
  libavformat    57.  4.100 / 57.  4.100
  libavformat    57.  4.100 / 57.  4.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavfilter     6. 11.100 /  6. 11.100
  libavfilter     6. 11.100 /  6. 11.100
  libavresample   3.  0.  0 /  3.  0.  0
  libavresample   3.  0.  0 /  3.  0.  0
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.100 /  2.  0.100
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.100 /  2.  0.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
root@thispc-sns:~/Documents/libfreenect/build/bin/Untitled Folder# Input #0, rawvideo, from '/dev/stdin':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: 184320 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (RGB[24] / 0x18424752), rgb24, 640x480, 184320 kb/s, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Please use -b:a or -b:v, -b is ambiguous
Input #0, rawvideo, from '/dev/stdin':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 184320 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (RGB[24] / 0x18424752), rgb24, 640x480, 184320 kb/s, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Please use -b:a or -b:v, -b is ambiguous
Output #0, avi, to 'sadra-depth.avi':
Output #0, avi, to 'sadra-rgb.avi':
  Metadata:
    ISFT            :   Metadata:
    ISFT            : Lavf57.4.100Lavf57.4.100

    Stream #0:0    Stream #0:0: Video: msmpeg4v3 (msmpeg4) (MP43 / 0x3334504D), yuv420p, 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 30000 kb/s: Video: msmpeg4v3 (msmpeg4) (MP43 / 0x3334504D), yuv420p, 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 30000 kb/s, , 20 fps, 20 fps, 20 tbn, 20 tbn, 20 tbc20 tbc

    Metadata:
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.6.100 msmpeg4      encoder         : Lavc57.6.100 msmpeg4
Stream mapping:

  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> msmpeg4v3 (msmpeg4))
 (rawvideo (native) -> msmpeg4v3 (msmpeg4))
***[rawvideo @ 0x2a31ce0] Invalid buffer size, packet size 483328 < expected frame_size 921600
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid argument
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=       6kB time=00:00:00.00*** bitrate=N/A    
video:0kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=       6kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A    
video:0kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)
Conversion failed!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following script on your machine, if you've installed opencv as well:

```
import freenect
import cv2
import numpy as np
from functions import *

def nothing(x):
    pass   
kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)     

def pretty_depth(depth):
    np.clip(depth, 0, 2**10 - 1, depth)
    depth >>= 2
    depth = depth.astype(np.uint8)
    return depth

while 1:

    dst = pretty_depth(freenect.sync_get_depth()[0])#input from kinect
    cv2.imshow('Video', dst)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('b'):
        break
```

Do you see a disparity map from your kinect ?